# Favorites api gives wrong results when sorted by added

Tags: bug, status-completed

For example, please compare http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/111391/favorites?sort=added with https://stackoverflow.com/api/userfavorites.html?userid=111391&page=1&pagesize=30&sort=added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.

Comment: I seem to have problems retrieving questions in the right order based on when they were "added", even on the StackExchange API site - http://goo.gl/W9JviD . I get the same result whether ordered by "asc" or "desc". What am I doing wrong?